# What are payloads in facebook messenger bot and how to handle them?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, bots

I want to send a button template message from my messenger bot. For example: set up a **flip coin** button which when pressed flips coin.

The bot already takes "flip a coin" command but how do I set that up with the button template message?

```
"payload":{
        "template_type":"button",
        "text":"FLIP A COIN",
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"flip A COIN",
            "payload":"flip(sender)"
          }
        ]
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you give a plain text such as FLIP_SENDER, then handle it accordingly.

You can get your payload from request.data.
Here is the sample code ( i have used Facebook's quick_reply button)

> var quickReplyPayload =
>   data.entry[0].messaging[0].message.quick_reply.payload;
>       var senderId = data.entry[0].messaging[0].sender.id;
>
> ```
> if(quickReplyPayload === 'FLIP_SENDER'){
>     console.log(quickReplyPayload);   
>     sendMessageToFacebook(senderId, response);
>     });
>
> }
> else if(quickReplyPayload === 'SOMETHING ELSE'){
>     sendMessageToFacebook(senderId, 'Another text');
> }
> else{
>     sendMessageToFacebook(senderId, 'Generic Text');
> }
> ```